# how can i do a feed of posts with flask and Jinja2?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm using the flask-SQLAchemy to manage my DB and i have a table named **post** with the columns **content, title, date, likes and profile_id**, in the feed i use a simple jinja2 template and  i send a variable with all posts in db, when i render the posts i make a for loop to render it but i can't take the name of the person who make the post (i have a variable with his id); So my question is how can i take the name of user who make the post in a jinja template?

Comment: where is the user's data saved? What's the relationship between both tables?
It would be very useful if you shared your code, like your models, flask methods and templates. That way it would be easier to help you.

Comment: This is my DB class
 `class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))


    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=user_id)

    def __ini__(self, content, title, date, user_id):
        self.content = content
        self.title = title 
        self.date = date
        self.user_id = user_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Post %r>"
`

Comment: and this is my route method:
```@app.route('/profile/<int:id>/')
def profile(id):
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(id=id)

    if current_user.id == id:
        return redirect(url_for("my_profile"))
    else:
        return render_template('profile.html',profile=user, posts=posts)
```

Comment: And my template has a for loop like this
```{{% for post in posts %}}
<p1> {{ post.title }}</p1>
<p1> {{ post.content }}</p1>
{{% endfor %}}
```

Comment: i want to take the name of who make the post,

Comment: My project it's like a twitter clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the column 'profile_id' the primary key? If so, then your post might be actually showing the ID of the post (i.e. the number that corresponds the primary key or the main column to identify a certain post) instead of what you want.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    profile_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Try analyzing the code above, I assume that's your code, what what you need to do is add another column which in this case the column known as the 'author', so do the following:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    profile_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    author = db.Column(db.String(250))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Done? Try opening a terminal and build your new model by doing the following:

`python name-of-your-app.py`

`from name-of-your-app import *`

`db.create_all()`

`exit()`

By doing this, you are making sure that your new model is actually being used instead of the old one. The next thing for you to do is add the 'author' column to your add function and edit function, then make sure to add a new input for the 'author' column in your jinja2 template and also replace the 'profile_id' with 'author'. If you are still confused, please refer to the code I've used while I was still learning flask. Also, consult to the provided link which I've also used to make the provided code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHGpPCYmPvI

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_simplelogin import SimpleLogin, is_logged_in
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'something-secret'
app.config['SIMPLELOGIN_USERNAME'] = 'admin'
app.config['SIMPLELOGIN_PASSWORD'] = 'admin'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
SimpleLogin(app)

class Blogpost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    posts = Blogpost.query.order_by(Blogpost.date_posted.desc()).all()

    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/add')
def add():
    if is_logged_in():
        return render_template('add.html')
    else:
        return redirect('/')

@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def post(post_id):
    post = Blogpost.query.filter_by(id=post_id).one()

    return render_template('post.html', post=post)

@app.route('/edit/<int:post_id>')
def edit(post_id):
    post = Blogpost.query.filter_by(id=post_id).one()
    if is_logged_in():
        return render_template('edit.html', post=post)
    else:
        return redirect('/')

@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
    title = request.form['title']
    subtitle = request.form['subtitle']
    author = request.form['author']
    content = request.form['content']
    post = Blogpost(title=title, subtitle=subtitle, author=author, content=content, date_posted=datetime.now())

    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/deletepost/<int:post_id>', methods=['POST'])
def deletepost(post_id):
    post = Blogpost.query.get_or_404(post_id)

    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/editpost/<int:post_id>', methods=['POST'])
def editpost(post_id):
    post = Blogpost.query.get_or_404(post_id)

    post.title = request.form['title']
    post.subtitle = request.form['subtitle']
    post.author = request.form['author']
    post.content = request.form['content']

    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I have the column ID this is the class:
`class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=user_id)
    def __ini__(self, content, title, date, user_id):
        self.content = content
        self.title = title 
        self.date = date
        self.user_id = user_id
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Post %r>"
`

Comment: This table has a relationship with the table user

Comment: I want to use the user_id(ForeignKey) for take the data user in the post like name and username

Comment: Sorry for late reply. And again, that's the problem, the column you're using doesn't actually return anything but an integer, what you could do instead is making a column dedicated to the username (i.e. "admin", "user1", "user2") as a string to actually show it to jinja. id and user_id should be one and the same instead of a separate entity because your app doesn't need that kind of complexity unless you are development a highly flexible app.

Comment: However, if you don't like to remove the column "user_id", no judgement here buddy. What I would recommend you to do is NOT to remove the "user_id" column, but instead, make an empty dictionary, and return that dictionary to the jinja template. Then make a condition basically saying "if user_id in dictionary.key", after that, return the value of a dictionary. You're not done yet, in your add_post template, make sure to add another input of the username, then process that username in order to be added in that dictionary. This solution is simple and completes your needs. Good Luck!